# How to inject Logger Service into exception filters

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, nest

I'm working on a NestJS application and trying to inject my logger service into an ExceptionFilter. Here's my code:

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  constructor(private readonly loggerService: LoggerService) {}

  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    ...
    this.loggerService.log(exception.message, 'error');
    ...
  }
}
```

I've registered the HttpExceptionFilter & LoggerService in my AppModule like this:

```
@Module({
  providers: [
    LoggerService,
    {
      provide: APP_FILTER,
      useClass: HttpExceptionFilter,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However, when the catch method of the HttpExceptionFilter is executed, I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'log')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your main file add

```
  const loggerService = await app.resolve(LoggerService);

  app.useGlobalFilters(
    new HttpExceptionFilter(loggerService),
  );
```